# Observer pattern in browser-javascript: subscribe to event "Dom element added" and handle this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, observer-pattern

I have a query:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').each(function() {
      // do smthing with form
    });
});
```

Forms may appear dynamically, i.e. built by javascript. I need to handle them just after load, smth like:

```
$('form').onload(function() {
   // it's called after new form was added to dom
});
```

I thought about using `setInterval`, but maybe HTML5 or new ES standards brought smth new...

Does anybody help to compose on load callback with aforementioned characteristics?

P.S. To clarify the purpose: I need to attach event handler to event "element was added to dom".

Comment: Why not have a couple of functions - one that creates the forms, another to process the forms after they're added to the DOM. Call one function after the other.

Comment: Could you show us your HTML?

Comment: It tooks too much time to refactor the code of existing site... I need smthing fast and tricky :)

Comment: @Dean Christian Armada, needed trick has nothing common with real html I have. Purpose is abstract - subscribe on new `form added to dom` event and handle form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was an event which is deprecated by now called "DOMNodeInserted", it would be wise to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events). with delegated events you can handle events on new elements that are dynamically add to DOM.

Comment: May I ask you about some snippet with DOMNodeInserted?

Comment: Yes, you can check it out on this fiddle that i made for u. http://jsfiddle.net/vhdmsm/2yg5n7L9/

Comment: Excellent, looks very promissing. And why DOMNodeInserted is deprecated :) ?

Comment: DOMNodeInserted isn't supported by IE (8 and below maybe) and is deprecated: w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a function

```
$(function() {
    function modForm() {
    $('form').each(function() {
      // do smthing with form
    });
    }
   modForm();
  $('a').click(function(){
    //add form dynamically
    $('body').append('<form>');
    //call the function agan
     modForm();
  });
});
```

Comment: Solution is concreate and ok. But may I subscribe on event `some element added to dom` and handle this element.

Comment: what do you mean by subscribe?

Comment: you will call the function when you update the DOM, for example: you add a new form `$('body').append('<form>');modForm();`and call the function after it

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern. I want DOM builder to notify me about new form was added, i.e. I want to subscibe on DOM builder event.

Comment: There's no such thing unless you code something for yourself.

Comment: I don't believe DOM builder doesn't implement object-observer. It's really  borring :( (for the future archaeologists, I am in 2015)